# How to make combobox autocomplete in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview, combobox, oledb

How can I adjust my code below so that I make the ComboBox autocomplete?

```vb
Private Sub PopulateComboBox()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSD UNION SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSG ORDER BY PNM"
    Try
        Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
            Using sda As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
                'Fill the DataTable with records from Table.
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                sda.Fill(dt)

                'Insert the Default Item to DataTable.
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()

                row(0) = ""
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)

                'Assign DataTable as DataSource.
                ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
                ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "PNM"
                ComboBox1.ValueMember = "PNM"
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch myerror As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    fillDataGridView1()
    fillDataGridView2()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends what you exactly want and need.

## You can only change the autocomplete property in code, when the FORM_LOAD event is proceeding, after that the changes will not take effect.

here are all three possibilities to manipulate the autocomplte

the `AutoCompleteMode` determines what kind of autocomplete so you want.

the rest is when you have an extra source for the autocompletio

```
    Dim source As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    source.AddRange(New String() _
                    {
                        "one",
                        "two",
                        "three",
                        "Four"
                    })
    With ComboBox1
        .AutoCompleteCustomSource = source
        .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    End With
```

Comment: thank you reply from you but I tried the code from you I tried in combobox it does not appear autocomplete.

Comment: and how can I use from my code i.e. datatable to combobox autocomplete

Comment: you can only change the behaviour in form load, so you have to set it there, it is a microsoft thing and can't be changed

Comment: Thank you for the reply from you. sorry I was late replying to you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a AutoCompleteStringCollection with the items and then add this as the AutoCompleteCustomSource.

An array of strings has to be created. To do this from the database, I would recommend using Entity Framework or a ORM package e.g. Dapper.

Here's an example. First of all install the Dapper Nuget Package to the project.

```
Imports Dapper

Private connectionString = "Server=xxxxx;Database=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;"

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = AutoSuggestList()
End Sub

Private Function AutoSuggestList() As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim collection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        collection.AddRange(connection.Query(Of String)("SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSD UNION SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GSG ORDER BY PNM").ToArray)
    End Using
    Return collection
End Function
```

Or to load asynchronously, you can use:

```
Private Async Function LoadAutoSuggestListAsync() As Task(Of AutoCompleteStringCollection)
    Dim collection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim list = Await connection.QueryAsync(Of String)(sqlText)
        collection.AddRange(list.ToArray)
    End Using
    Return collection
End Function

Private Async Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ComboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = Await LoadAutoSuggestListAsync()
End Sub
```

Also building the list is not limited to the loading event.

By the way, Microsoft recommends not using the System.Data.OleDb library, as it is older technology. I recommend using the System.Data.SqlClient library.